# BrightSpace Valence API getting started issues

Tags: desire2learn

I'm attempting to set up and run the basic code sample (python version) found [here](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/samples/gettingStarted.html).

Unfortunately the provided login page fails to resolve (http://lms.valence.desire2learn.com/).
Is there a different sample host I can use to verify my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; that test host has been retired and replaced by a new one that's associated with the [Brightspace Developer Community](https://community.brightspace.com/s/topic/0TO610000000JcwGAE/developer). To use it, you will need to be a Developer Community member and [use a test user provisioned on the new developer environment host](https://community.brightspace.com/s/article/New-Dev-Environment-for-Extensibility-Experimentation).

Comment: Thanks Viktor, I'll go through that resource.